# VBA Acrobat JSO Save in For Loop overwrites after 96 Files

Tags: javascript, vba, acrobat

I'm working on a VBA macro that loops through a large spreadsheet, exports each line to XML, imports the XML file into a PDF form (XFA architecture) and then saves each populated form to a pre-defined folder.  The problem is, after 96 iterations (repeatedly tested), each newly completed PDF causes the oldest PDF to disappear from the folder.  The code being looped is as follows:

```
Sub AcroExport()

Dim OutputPath As String
Dim theForma As New AcroAVDoc
Dim theform As AcroPDDoc
Dim jso As Object
OutputPath = GetMyDocuments()

ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("1042-S_Map").Export OutputPath & "f1042sExportTemp.xml", True

If theForma.Open("C:\Users\E050704\Desktop\f1042s.pdf", "") Then

    Set theform = theForma.GetPDDoc
    Set jso = theform.GetJSObject
    jso.importXFAData OutputPath & "f1042sExportTemp.xml"
    theform.Save 1, OutputPath & "1042-S_K-1_Output\" & "Form 1042-S - " & Range("ReciptNameCell").Value & ".pdf"
    theForma.Close True

End If

End Sub
```

I've also tried the SaveAs method from the JavaScript Object, with slightly different results (still 96 files, but instead of deleting the oldest file, it simply doesn't create new ones).

Totally stumped on how to make it keep more than 96 files.  Any help is much appreciated.

For reference, I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise, Excel 2007 and Acrobat 9 Standard (Version 9.4.6).